# Methodologies for data leakage detection?

Tags: data-leakage

Are there any specific methodologies related to Informational Data Leakage Detection? I am searching for a methodologi on Informational Data Leakage Detection for a company assessment but I am a bit lost.

For example I am looking for something like OWASP Testing Guide but this is for Penetration Testing/Vulnerability Assessment.

Comment: You can calculate probability of data leakage based on the amount of access to particular data and the position of people who have it. So for example, if there's HR system where 5 sysadmins have access, there's 100% chance it has been leaked. But if only CEO has access (and that it's proven nobody else accessed it), the probability of leakage is a lot less.

Comment: Pattern matching and data/channel classification. Data that looks like a pre-defined pattern should not traverse this boundary. Data of classification X should not traverse into a channel of a lower classification. Now the trick is: how can you determine that the data being inspected is of the certain pattern or classification ...